# Consolidating 2 regex patterns into one

Tags: php, regex

I wrote 2 preg_match statements to extract TN, type and extension from a log dump.  Is there a way to consolidate the 2 preg_match statements into one and still get the correct extraction?

```
preg_match("/(\d{3} \d \d{2} \d{2})   (\w{3,}).+(\d{4,}+)$/", $newstr, $match_array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 29);
if (empty($match_array))
   preg_match("/(\d{3} \d \d{2} \d{2})   (\w{3,})/", $newstr, $match_array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 29);
```

I attempted this and it didn't work

```
preg_match("/(\d{3} \d \d{2} \d{2})   (\w{3,}).+(\d{4,}+)$|(\d{3} \d \d{2} \d{2})   (\w{3,})/", $newstr, $match_array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 29);
```

Data file content:

```
1140E     19 SEP 2018   00   252 1 11 05   1140                         8D  4090
1140E     19 SEP 2018   00   252 1 11 06   1140                         8D  
1140E      4 SEP 2019   00   252 1 11 07   1140                         8D  5592
```

Matches:

```
252 1 11 05, 1140, 4090
252 1 11 06, 1140
252 1 11 07, 1140, 5592
```

Comment: Why not use `$row = fgetcsv` with tab delimiter and use `$row[5]` 6,7,8,9,11 ???  Or `file` and `preg_split` on whitespace and do the same?

Comment: @AbraCadaver you should post that as an answer...

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I am not sure whether preg_split can handle scenario where there is no limiter.  I also have log files where first column contains IP address which can take up to 15 characters and second column contains phone type which starts from 16th character.  I want to standardize the method of data extraction.  For the scope of this question, your solution would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the last capture group in your original regex optional, and change the `.+` before it to `.+?` to make it lazy so that the regex will still capture the closing digits if they are present. For example:

```
$strings = [
    '1140E     19 SEP 2018   00   252 1 11 05   1140                         8D  4090',
    '1140E     19 SEP 2018   00   252 1 11 06   1140                         8D  ',
    '1140E      4 SEP 2019   00   252 1 11 07   1140                         8D  5592'
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match('/(\d{3} \d \d{2} \d{2})   (\w{3,}).+?(\d{4,})?$/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 252 1 11 05   1140                         8D  4090
    [1] => 252 1 11 05
    [2] => 1140
    [3] => 4090
)
Array
(
    [0] => 252 1 11 06   1140                         8D  
    [1] => 252 1 11 06
    [2] => 1140
)
Array
(
    [0] => 252 1 11 07   1140                         8D  5592
    [1] => 252 1 11 07
    [2] => 1140
    [3] => 5592
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WW3TO)

Comment: For some reason, it would only work for me after I insert 2 white spaces between .+ and ?.  I tested it @ https://regex101.com/r/er3bAM/1.  Yes, this solution works as requested.

Comment: @Singsiblaw you didn't quite copy it correctly to regex101. See https://regex101.com/r/er3bAM/2